# How to define the matrix that will later contain Mandelbrot

Tags: python, matrix, mandelbrot

I recently developed a simple function that does the work of defining whether a complex number is stable or not, to display the Mandelbrot set. She looks like this:

```py
def mandelbrot(x, y):
    c = complex(x, y)
    z = 0

    for i in range(50):
        z = z**2 + c

        if abs(z) >= 2:
            break
        # else, display pixel via x,y ...
```

I now have a problem defining the matrix. The matrix, in real life, will look like:
[Mandelbrot's matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGcdC.png)

But, when I try to represent it, it doesn't work because the matrix can't accept negative arguments or floating arguments. So, when I enter this:

```py
x1 = -2.1
x2 = 0.6
y1 = -1.2
y2 = 1.2

img = np.zeros((x1 - x2, y1 - y2, 3))
```

I have this:

```py
    img = np.zeros((x1 - x2, y1 - y2, 3))
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

An idea to represent the Mandelbrot matrix?

Comment: The dimensions for the matrix should be integer - that is what the interpreter tells you. You can scale the coordinates to fit the integer coordinates after the calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can't create matrix with float axis sizes. Use some scaler, like k=1000 and shift like dx=2.1, dy = 1.2 to draw on matrix.

```
img = np.zeros((int(k*(x1 - x2 + dx)), int(k*(y1 - y2+dy)), 3))
```

when displaying pixel:

```
img[int(k*(x + dx)), int(k*(y + dy)] = ...
```